# how to insert unique values in database

Tags: java, android, sql

i am using following method to insert name in database

```
 public void insertContact(String name) 
 {
 ContentValues newContact = new ContentValues();
 newContact.put("name", name);

 open(); // open the database
 database.insert("contacts", null, newContact);
 close(); // close the database
 } // end method insertContact
```

can i made some kind of check to stop data duplication. I mean to say if name already exist
in data base it should not insert the new one.

Comment: Add a unique constraint to your name field in your contacts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a rule in database on a table for unique values on a column. Then if you try to add a duplicate value an exception will be thrown.

See this example to set the unique rule: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in MS SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD CONSTRAINT my_const_1 UNIQUE( [columnname] );
```